# Azure storage account suspect activity

Tags: azure, azure-storage

So I create a storage account on azure and started using a file share for some days, but then I noticed some activity any hour during any day, even after stopping using the file share and deleted it:

[image: Azure storage account activity]

I'm showing tables activity here because is where there's activity every hour, on other resources like tables and queues there's sporadic activity too, but I don't have anything on this storage account

After noticed this I try some things thinking about a security hole:

- I tried to rotate access keys, several times
- I even deleted and recreated the storage account with no avail, this was still showing the previous activity (can this be related that I used the same storage account name?)

This is not running in a production environment but still I don't know what is going on

Is this some background process of azure or do I need to worry about it?

Comment: There's nothing suspect that I see. There could be all sorts of things happening in the background (like periodic health checks, diagnostics, etc). Also, the amount of bandwidth is negligible. Since you said you are showing Tables metrics: have you looked to see if there is any diagnostic data being written? (since that's where it's typically found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Makogon said, it turned out that was diagnostic activity, i disabled it in Diagnostic logs (classic) and the activity was gone.

Glad to know that my account wasn't hacked or something like that.